# Multiple True if statements for multiple actions on same GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a small game project (first time learning C# so the coding is pretty terrible).

I have a yellow cube that changes colour to green after both the yellow and blue cube have been selected by bools. I got that code working and copied it over to purple script on the blue cube to change it to purple. Playing the game executes the green colour script even when clicking the red cube and manually checking the bools in the inspector ignores the purple action part of the script.

The code works by selecting a cube and selecting another cube, with the 1st cube executing the script that causes a colour change and kills the second cube. Blue cube and yellow cube selected turns a blue cube into a green cube and kills yellow cube. When I wanted to select a blue cube and red cube by my modified green cube code, the code doesn't execute.

Blue Script on the cube (working)

```
    public bool bluetopurple = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    render.material.color = Color.blue;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        bluetopurple = true;

    }
```

Green Script (working)

```
public class greenscript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject yellow;
    public yellowscript yellow1;
    public GameObject blue;
    public bluescript blue1;
    public bool green;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    blue1 = GameObject.Find("blue").GetComponent<bluescript> ();
    blue1.bluetopurple = false;

    yellow1 = GameObject.Find("yellow").GetComponent<yellowscript> ();
    yellow1.yellowchange = false; 
    green = false;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (yellow1.yellowchange == true) {
        if (blue1.bluetopurple == true) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                green = true; 
            }
            if (green == true) {
                Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
                render.material.color = Color.green;
                Destroy ((blue), 0.0f);
            }
```

Purple Script (not working, variables have been changed correctly and no error codes appear in debugger):

```
public class purplescript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject red;
public redscript red1;
public GameObject blue;
public bluescript blue1;
public bool purple;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    blue1 = GameObject.Find("blue").GetComponent<bluescript> ();
    blue1.bluetopurple = false;

    red1 = GameObject.Find("red").GetComponent<redscript> ();
    red1.redtopurple = false;
    purple = false;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (red1.redtopurple == true) {
        if (blue1.bluetopurple == true) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                purple = true; 
            }
            if (purple == true) {
                Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
                render.material.color = Color.magenta;
                Destroy ((red), 0.0f);
            }
```

I expected that the green cube script would be easily modified by changing the variables to the other cubes I wanted to select but apparently not and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of

```
GameObject.Find("blue").GetComponent<bluescript>();
```

rather use

```
FindObjectOfType<bluescript>();
```

this is way more efficient. Or if possible don't even use it at all but rather reference the according components to your scripts already in the Inspector.

---

I didn't really understand what you are trying to achieve but note that `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is `true` on **every** GameObject .. not only the one you currently hover with the mouse pointer!

If you wanted to implement something that should happen when you click on a specific GameObject (with a `Collider` or a `GUIElement`) then rather use [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html). Also you are doing a lot of unneccesary stuff in `Update` which is called every frame so there might be some issues as well.

Then there are a lot of small issues in your code

1. for your blue script

   ```
   Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();
   render.material.color = Color.blue;
   ```

   Having this in your `Update` method makes no sense because

   - it is extremly unefficient to call `GetComponent` over and over again especially every frame
   - you don't change anything by that ... so set the color only once at start

   so it should probably rather look like

   ```
   public class bluescript : MonoBehaviour
   {
       public bool bluetopurple = false;

       // Use this for initialization
       private void Start () 
       {
           Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();
           render.material.color = Color.blue;
       } 

       // Catch the mousedown
       private void OnMouseDown()
       {
           bluetopurple = true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. similar issues are also found in the greenscript. You call the same code over and over again every frame in `Update`, `blue` might not be set so it might not get destroyed but throw an error. Also

   ```
   Destroy(blue, 0.0f);
   ```

   Here you destroy a **Component** - not the GameObject! I guess you wanted to do `Destroy(blue.gameObject);` .. also passing `0.0f` can be skipped because it is `0` be default anyway.

   ```
   public class greenscript : MonoBehaviour 
   {
       // If possible set these already in the Inspector and don't use
       // Find and GetComponent at all
       public yellowscript yellow;
       public bluescript blue;
       public Renderer render;

       public bool green;

       // Use this for initialization
       private void Start () 
       {
           Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();

           blue = FindObjectOfType<bluescript>();
           blue.bluetopurple = false;

           yellow = FindObjectOfType<yellowscript> ();
           yellow.yellowchange = false; 

           green = false;
       }

       private void OnMouseDown()
       {
           if (!yellow.yellowchange) return;

           // if you destroyed the blue GameObject already
           // checking this again would throw an error so catch that case
           if(!blue) return;

           if (!blue.bluetopurple) return;

           green = true;

           render.material.color = Color.green;

           Destroy(blue.gameObject);
       }
   }
   ```
3. And finally the purplescript

   ```
   public class purplescript : MonoBehaviour 
   {
       public redscript red;
       public bluescript blue;
       public Renderer render;

       public bool purple;

       // Use this for initialization
       void Start() 
       {
           Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();

           blue = FindObjectOfType<bluescript>();
           blue.bluetopurple = false;

           red = FindObjectOfType<redscript>();
           red.redtopurple = false;

           purple = false;
       }

       private void OnMouseDown()
       {
           // here again check if the object still exists first
           if(!red) return;

           if(!red.redtopurple) return;
           if(!blue.bluetopurple) return;

           purple = true;

           render.material.color = Color.magenta;

           Destroy(red.gameObject);
       }
   }
   ```

You didn't show the code for the `redscript` and `yellowscript`. In the `greenscript` you `Destroy(blue)` but in the `purplescript` you rely on `blue.bluetopurple` .. this doesn't seem right.

---

#### Alternative and better scaleable/maintainable solution

From the scripts I see here you could simplify it a lot by using only **2 single** scripts a:

- ScriptA: Doesn't rely on any other script but only chnages its color and bool on click
- ScriptB: Kind of does the same but only takes a click when two other scripts' values are true, changes its color, destroys one of the other scripts' GameObjects

All the rest like *Which values to check*, *which color do I turn to*, *which object do I destroy* you can set via parameters in the Inspector. So you would only have

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Base-Components")]
    public Renderer renderer;

    [Header("Base-Settings")]
    // start with this color
    public Color InitialColor = Color.white;
    // turn to this after being clicked
    public Color TargetColor = Color.white;

    [Header("Values")]
    public bool WasClicked;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    private void SetUp()
    {
        if(!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.color = InitialColor;

        WasClicked = false;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        HandleClick();
    }

    // make this virtual so we can extend/overwrite it in child classes
    protected virtual void HandleClick()
    {
        WasClicked = true;
        renderer.material.color = TargetColor;
    }
}
```

Now since the second script is kind of very similar but only extends the behaviour inherit from ScriptA. This means it will have all the properties and methods already implemented but now you can extend the ones implemented as `virtual`:

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour
{
    // What does this script have, ScriptA didn't?
    [Header("Additional Components")]
    // The two components you want to check the bool for
    public ScriptA FirstToCheck;
    public ScriptA SecondToCheck;
    [Space]
    // The component you want to destroy
    public ScriptA ToDestroy;

    // Overwrite/Extend the behaviour of HandleClick
    protected virtual void HandleClick()
    {
        // One of the references doesn't exist 
        // so object was probably already destroyed
        if(!ToDestroy || !FirstToCheck || !SecondToCheck) return;

        // One of the objects wasn't clicked yet
        if(!FirstToCheck.WasClicked || !SecondToCheck.WasClicked) return;

        // Do what the parent implemented
        // in this case set my bool and change my color
        base.HandleClick();

        Destroy(ToDestroy.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Place the `ScriptA` on the cube(s) that doesn't rely on others in order to be activated. And `ScriptB` on the cubes that check two other cubes first. Then configure all the parameters in the Inspector and already set the references between all those objects.

Comment: Thanks for all the help DerHugo, I'll implement all the changes you've recommended and I didn't even know about the virtual class.

Answer (score 0):

you should not have 3 classes for each cube...You should have a class attached to all the cubes, and a variable that sets the inspector what color the cube has,and bool actived. Then have a main class that contains an array with all the cubes. And you need an abstract class that has an abstract method Activate, each cube extends the abstract class. In the main class when you click on a cube, take the abstract class from it and call the method Activate.

Comment: So you can avoid having the same script on multiple objects, just execute the one you click

Comment: Thanks for the input George, I'll try and condense them to two scripts as I learn more.